# Printing arrays while determining number of characters

Tags: c, arrays

My intention is randoming number between 0 & 1000 and print how mamy characters the number have? Then print another number and adding its character number to the total of character number.Code below compiles and windows gives runtime error after running.Couldn't find the error in the code.What is my error?

```
int main()
{
    char str [1000];
    int i=0;
    int k,a=0;

    printf("Number \tTotal\n");
    for(k=0;k!=10;k++)
    {
        i=rand()%1000;
        str[k]=i;
        printf("%s",str[k]);
        a+=strlen(str);
        printf("%s \t%d\n",str[k],a);
          }       


    getch();

    return 0;




    }
```

Comment: It solved runtime but now numbers seems odd characters like >>>>

Comment: Strlen counting numbers no error on that part

Comment: `printf("%s",str[k]);` is wrong. `str[k]` is a character, not a string.

Comment: I ve changed it %c but now its printing numbers like >>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert number to string first.

```
i = rand() % 1000;
length = snprintf(str, 1000, "%d", i); // Convert integer to string
printf("%s", str); // Print current string
a += length; // Add length
printf("%s \t%d\n", str, a); // Print current string and length so far
```

Comment: @Psybonaut There are several ways to do this: Calculate characters manually, divide number by 10 until it is zero... You will have to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` should be `%c` since you are just printing a `char`. `a+=strlen(str)` adds the previous `strlen` together. While you are printing the current `char` along with the most recent length of `str`.

`int j` is also unused.

You are printing `str[k]` twice, so it "doubles" up the characters on the line. If you want to store a more reasonable result, then reduce your random number down to 100. Also, I would reset `a` to 0 after every iteration in your loop.

Example output with changes:

```
Sayi    Toplam
S       5
V       5
M       5
        5
]       5
#       6
V       7
\       10
1       10
        10
```

Comment: I used your advice and now it printf number like >>>> Why?It seems strlen working right!

Comment: I know i will delete! But look my comments pls!

Answer (score 0):

You are storing `i`, a number between 0 an 9999 in `str`, a character string, then taking the length of that invalid string.  If you want to count the digits in the random number, you need to convert it to a string first with `sprintf(str,"%d",i)`.